# UrlRewrite via appcmd

Tags: url-rewriting, appcmd

I want to create urlrewrite url using appcmd for redirecting all requests from

> http://

to

> https://

I tried to google but nothing found. Could you provide me some basic example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got it working with this:

```
appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/rewrite/rules /+"[name='http_redirect',enabled='True']" /commit:apphost

appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/rewrite/rules.[name='http_redirect'] /match.url:"(.*)" /match.ignoreCase:true /commit:apphost

appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/rewrite/rules.[name='http_redirect'].conditions/add /+"[input='{HTTPS}',pattern='off']" /commit:apphost

appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/rewrite/rules.[name='http_redirect'].action /+"[type='Redirect',url='https://{HOST_NAME}/{R:1}',redirectType='Found']" /commit:apphost
```

This [link](http://blogs.iis.net/eokim/archive/2010/06/02/understanding-appcmd-exe-list-set-config-configurationpath-section-name-parameter-name-value.aspx) can help on building *appcmd* scripts.

Answer (score 4):

For the benefit of anyone else looking (as I was) you can do the following to insert your new rule at the start, end or a particular position in the list, as just adding it to the end by default may result in the rule not being hit:

```
appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/rewrite/rules /+"[@start,name='http_redirect',enabled='True']" /commit:apphost
appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/rewrite/rules /+"[@end,name='http_redirect',enabled='True']" /commit:apphost
appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/rewrite/rules /+"[@2,name='http_redirect',enabled='True']" /commit:apphost
```

Source:

```
appcmd.exe set config /?
```

Comment: i didn't know it was a simple as /?, and it works on subsections as well. saved my life

Answer (score 0):

In my case the syntax is slightly different since I wanted to alter a URL Rewrite rule at the root (server) level.

```
appcmd set config -section:system.webServer/rewrite/globalRules -[name='myRule'].action.url:http://myRewrite /commit:apphost
```

It took me a long time to figure out the globalRules instead of rules difference.